Why the Bridge Edge Loop doesn’t work on these 2 edges?

I can’t seemed to create a face between these 2 orange highlighted edges? Can anyone explain to me why?

Hello please share your file

@moonboots the problem is that I forgot to Ctrl J before I Bridge edging it, and it is solved, but thanks alot for asking
